# Getting token_type=Application, instead of bearer in DocuSign /oauth/token

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting the token_type=Application in DocuSign OAuth API.
As per the documentation it is supposed to be Bearer. 
API endpoint is https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token

Comment: do you have an integration key? what exactly are you doing to get the token?

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting the token incorrectly. If you're using JWT, then you need to include the guid of the account user who will be impersonated by the access token. It will be a `bearer` token.

While DocuSign's IdP can produce application tokens, they're only used with the Org API.